# Preselect child dropdown value which is dependent on parent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 2 dropdown i.e. Parent & Child dropdown

```
<select id="parentDropdown">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="childDropdown">
</select>
```

ChildDropdown values are based on parentDropdown selection, and a separate onChange function is written to get childDropdown values through parentDropdown change. And, it's working perfectly fine as values in childDropdown are coming correct.

Now, in one of the functionality, parentDropdown & childDropdown values coming from another Ajax method and I just need to pre-select both the dropdown values.

```
//Parent Dropdown
var parentDropdownVal = response.parentDropdownVal;
if((typeof parentDropdownVal !== 'undefined') && (parentDropdownVal !== '')){
  $('#parentDropdown').val(parentDropdownVal).trigger('change');
}


//Child Dropdown
var childDropdownVal = response.childDropdownVal;
if((typeof childDropdownVal !== 'undefined') && (childDropdownVal !== '')){
    $('#childDropdown').val(childDropdownVal).trigger('change');
}
```

**The problem I'm facing is**: Parent dropdown is getting set. But, childDropdown value is not getting selected. Since, parentDropdown is triggering change method, so refreshed/corresponding values should come to childDropdown. And, dropdown values in childDropdown are also coming. But, not pre-selecting the childDropdown which is coming from another ajax method.

But, when I put alert inside, values for childDropdown are getting pre-selected.

```
//Child Dropdown
var childDropdownVal = response.childDropdownVal;
if((typeof childDropdownVal !== 'undefined') && (childDropdownVal !== '')){
    alert("hello");
    $('#childDropdown').val(childDropdownVal).trigger('change');
}
```

I tried

**1)** `$('#parentDropdown option:contains('+parentDropdownVal+')').prop('selected', true);`

**2)** `$('#parentDropdown option').eq(parentDropdownVal).attr('selected', 'selected');`

**3)** `$('#childDropdown').val(childDropdownVal).trigger('change');`

Any help/hint/suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Looks like a timing problem. Try to set the child options first, then the parent options. So by the time parent gets selected and triggers its change event, child already has its options.

Comment: @Thomas: I can't set child options first as it is totally dependent on what parentDropdown is selected. Yeah, it's a timing problem which I also thinks too.

Comment: Thought so. The correct way would be to set the options of child in the change-event-listener of parent. afterwards check if `response.childDropdownVal` is set and set this as the selected option. all this code belongs inside the event listener.

Comment: is it an option to chain the two ajax calls? `$.ajax({}).done($.ajax({}).done())`

Comment: Actually, there are 3-4 dropdown dependent on each other values. And, a separate onChange function written for all the dropdown. So, when I'm triggering `$('#parentDropdown').val(parentDropdownVal).trigger('change');`. Automatically, dropdown values for child dropdown is coming. It's not getting selected. That's the problem @Mihai @Thomas

Comment: By the time you set the value from your response, child has no options. That's the problem. You need to make sure child has options before you set the value. That's the reason it works when you trigger an alert.